# unable take input from a text file in python crawler

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a basic crawler in python, I want to take input from a text file.

I used open/raw_input but there was an error.

When I used input("") function it is prompting for input and was working fine.
The problem only with reading a file

```
     import re

     import urllib.request

     url = open('input.txt', 'r')


     data =  urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
     data1 = data.decode("utf8")
     print(data1)

     file =open('output.txt' , 'w')
     file.write(data1)
     file.close()
```

error output below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 8, in <module>
    data =  urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 518, in open
    protocol = req.type
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `open` returns a file object, and not the content of the file as a string. if you want `url` to contain the content as a string, change the line to:

`url = open('input.txt', 'r').read()`

Comment: Great , it's working now . I was scratching my head for hours . Also can you help in multiple websites in input.txt and multiple output.txt should be created for each website. When I try it says Invalid